# What to call someone who only works when it's visible?

Tags: single-word-requests

What can I call someone who makes sure that other people know about the helpful or good deeds they do?

They aren't evil otherwise, they just want to make sure everyone knows how much they are doing.

E.g. only takes the trash out when someone else is home with them, and says "I'm going to take the trash out." After tidying up they tell you "I tidied everything up".

Comment: This doesn't match your request (you should really include a sample sentence, [as the SWR tag says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), to help people come up with a good answer), but such work could be described as "performative". [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/performative) says "made or done for show (as to bolster one's own image or make a positive impression on others)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with what was said in an earlier comment. Performative is the word I would use to describe a person who does things for show (i.e., only when someone else will know about them).

Here's one definition of performative from dictionary.com:

> relating to ways of behaving that exhibit a socially acceptable belief, trait, or quality, often making a superficial impression

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/performative

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).